# Executing Functions in R

Tags: r, function

I have a function that creates one table from many `.csv` files and then does something to that table.  The function looks something like this:

```
functionName <- function(directory) {

  tempTable <- list.files(directory, all.files = TRUE)
  allFilesTable <- lapply(tempTable, read.csv)

  doSomethingWithNonNAValues(allFilesTable, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

When I run the following lines at the console, I get the behavior I want:

```
  > tempTable <- list.files(getwd(), all.files = TRUE)
  > allFilesTable <- lapply(tempTable, read.csv)
  > doSomethingWithNonNAValues(allFilesTable, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, when I try to use the above FUNCTION to do the exact same thing, I get an error:

```
> functionName(getwd())
 Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input 
5 stop("no lines available in input") 
4 read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...) 
3 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2 lapply(tempTable, read.csv) 
1 functionName(getwd())
```

Why would the commands work in the console, but not when called from the function?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing this:

```
functionName <- function(directory) {
  tempTable <- list.files(directory, all.files = TRUE)
etc.
```

to this:

```
functionName <- function(directory) {
     tempTable <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".csv")
etc.
}
```

[Patric] Modify the code slightly, the previous code listed all file including non ".csv" file and than error-ed out at "read.csv". The modified code only list
".csv" file so that it works very well.